# How to install GNU Objective-C on OS X?

Tags: macos, development

I have OS X Mavericks and I want to try to learn Objective-C(++). For this, I need to install the gobjc compiler, how do it (I've tried to install gobjc from sources but it's still not present)?

Comment: Is there a specific reason *not* to install Xcode from the App Store?

Comment: and note to bootstrap getting any compiler etc you will need to install Xcode

Answer (score 1):

The most straightforward way to install an Objective-C compiler is by installing Xcode (which is available free from the App Store). It gives you both the IDE and the command-line compilers (there's an option inside Xcode to install the latter). If you don't want to install the IDE, you can install the command-line tools only using `xcode-select --install`.

Once you have the command-line tools installed, you can use them to bootstrap GCC if you'd prefer to use that.

Comment: Is XCode command tools free?

Comment: @sosolal Yes, Xcode and the command line tools are freely installable on Mavericks.

Comment: I mean as in freedom: www.gnu.org/philosophy/free-sw.html

Comment: @sosolal Sorry, thought you meant as in beer :) I don't know if *all* of them are free, but the compiler suite is LLVM, which is BSD licensed. Of course Apple have probably applied their own patches to it, but the compiler itself is open source.

Comment: But gobjc doesn't works, Xcode or not.

Comment: @sosolal If you're install the GNU compiler suite from sources, you'll need a compiler to bootstrap it (hence the requirement to install the Xcode command-line tools first, to give you the compiler to bootstrap it).

Comment: Okay, I install the compiler from the sources a second time.

Comment: This doesn't works : gobjc is still not present

Comment: @sosolal Is the compiler not called `gcc`, as with the other GNU C compilers?

Comment: No, GNU Objective-C is gobjc as GNU C++ is g++.

Comment: I've not tried it on OS X, but you can certainly use `gcc` on Linux to compile Objective-C (assuming `gobjc` is installed).

Comment: This IS exactly the problem : gobjc is not installed